# how to know every request sent by an application

Tags: apprequests

I want to develop an application which gives alert messages for my clients.

Their's an application called ODIN DIET which brings Intraday data.

I have used Fiddler see the requests sent by ODIN DIET , but the ODIN DIET sends the http

request only for login purpose not for anything I think ODIN Diet is getting data from an

another source like ftp or download data from somewhere.

Coming to the point i want to know every request sent by ODIN DIET like HTTP,FTP and all

other sources.

NOTE : - ODIN DIET brings data from somewhere every second.And i have used fiddler and it doesn't helped me because its not sending http request.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at some of the SysInternals tools ([Technet Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021)) which were acquired by Microsoft.  Specifically the process monitor will probably do what you are after.  You can watch all file and registry access by an app using this.

Comment: their are many links here can you give my the exact download link http://live.sysinternals.com/WindowsInternals/

Comment: Click on the technet link I gave you.  IT has all the tools, including the process monitor for you to download.